# How to select a field using XPATH with filter from repeating segment?

Tags: xpath

How to select field using XPATH with filter from repeating segment?
I need TDFORMAT> value only when TDID> is "ZPRA"?

[XML here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBnKq.jpg)

Comment: Do not post code as image! Always post code in a `code` section as text.

Comment: As zx485 said, please add your XML as text and format it as a code block.  The reason for this is that it makes it easier for people to reproduce your issue and come up with a solution.

Comment: the XML was not formatted well after i tried to paste it, and I couldn't reformat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XPath-1.0 expression

```
//E1EDKT1[TDID="ZPRA"]/E1EDKT2/TDFORMAT
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reaction, i found that ./../E1EDKT1/E1EDKT2[./../TDID="ZPRA"]/TDFORMAT works too but yours looks more clean. Thank you